# HTML Even Sized Cards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently trying to make a website and I'm a beginner in HTML/CSS/Bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap v4.6.0

Here's my full code for the page: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ariefpambudiii/pen/ExoozvM)

So my problem is I can't seem to get an even sized 2x2 grid when a card doesnt have anything inside it

[image]

But when I have some things inside it, it's working just fine
[image]

I also have problems with scrollable div, while I'm adding more item to this section, it won't detected my items as overflow, but instead its enlarging the container:
[image]

Here's the code for "SURAT TERKAIT" section:

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-column p-0" style="background-color: transparent; align-items:center; justify-content: space-around">
                                <div class="row w-100">
                                    <div class="container" style="background-color: white; color:black; padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px; border-radius: 10px; flex-direction: row; display: flex;">
                                        <table class="w-100">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>No.</th>
                                                <th>Tanggal Surat</th>
                                                <th>Pemohon</th>
                                                <th>Tanggal Acara</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>122 xx212 2221</td>
                                                <td>01/01/2021</td>
                                                <td>asdasda asd as</td>
                                                <td>01/02/2021</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <button style=" border-radius: 5px !important; border: none; font-weight: 5vh; background-color: #333333;"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf" style="color: red; font-size: 2vh"></i></button>
                                        <button style=" border-radius: 5px !important; border: none; font-weight: 5vh; background-color: white"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down" style="color: #333333; font-size: 2vh"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row w-100">
                                    <div class="container" style="background-color: white; color:black; padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px; border-radius: 10px; flex-direction: row; display: flex;">
                                        <table class="w-100">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>No.</th>
                                                <th>Tanggal Surat</th>
                                                <th>Pemohon</th>
                                                <th>Tanggal Acara</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>122 xx212 2221</td>
                                                <td>01/01/2021</td>
                                                <td>asdasda asd as</td>
                                                <td>01/02/2021</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <button style=" border-radius: 5px !important; border: none; font-weight: 5vh; background-color: #333333;"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf" style="color: red; font-size: 2vh"></i></button>
                                        <button style=" border-radius: 5px !important; border: none; font-weight: 5vh; background-color: white"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down" style="color: #333333; font-size: 2vh"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row w-100">
                                    <div class="container" style="background-color: white; color:black; padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px; border-radius: 10px; flex-direction: row; display: flex;">
                                        <table class="w-100">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>No.</th>
                                                <th>Tanggal Surat</th>
                                                <th>Pemohon</th>
                                                <th>Tanggal Acara</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>122 xx212 2221</td>
                                                <td>01/01/2021</td>
                                                <td>asdasda asd as</td>
                                                <td>01/02/2021</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <button style=" border-radius: 5px !important; border: none; font-weight: 5vh; background-color: #333333;"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf" style="color: red; font-size: 2vh"></i></button>
                                        <button style=" border-radius: 5px !important; border: none; font-weight: 5vh; background-color: white"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down" style="color: #333333; font-size: 2vh"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row w-100">
                                    <div class="container" style="background-color: white; color:black; padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px; border-radius: 10px; flex-direction: row; display: flex;">
                                        <table class="w-100">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>No.</th>
                                                <th>Tanggal Surat</th>
                                                <th>Pemohon</th>
                                                <th>Tanggal Acara</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>122 xx212 2221</td>
                                                <td>01/01/2021</td>
                                                <td>asdasda asd as</td>
                                                <td>01/02/2021</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <button style=" border-radius: 5px !important; border: none; font-weight: 5vh; background-color: #333333;"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf" style="color: red; font-size: 2vh"></i></button>
                                        <button style=" border-radius: 5px !important; border: none; font-weight: 5vh; background-color: white"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down" style="color: #333333; font-size: 2vh"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

So my question is:

1. How can I make all of the 2x2 grid evenly sized?
2. How can I make the "SURAT TERKAIT" section have a scrollable (lets say I just want 4 items maximum displayed)

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you want the children of a flex element to be equally sized you can use `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0;` or the equivalent short-hand `flex: 1`.

Comment: @bluecouch thank you for your answer, I will try this on my code now much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `max-size` and `min-size` to your Grid to have the size fix and it will not be dependent on the data.

For scroll, have a div over all the grids giving a height to it like `height: 500px`, and add css: `overflow: scroll;`